# Integrate an UIScrollView to an existing view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a View in a xib file and a corresponding ViewController.
With Interface Builder I put an image, some labels and now a table view in it.

What I want to have, is that the whole view will be scrollable, because the new table view is currently only scrolling inside the tableview boundaries.

How can I put a scroll view behind this existing view with IB?

I already put a UIScrollView to the IB and put all other elements on it. Also I create an UIScrollView IBOutlet and connect it, but the screen is not scrollable...

Do I have to do something like

```
[myScrollView addSubview: ???];
```

Thank you a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the contentSize property of the scrollview before it is usable. Yeah, I know - freaking ridiculous that this isn't automatic.

Just do `myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(int, int)`.

Comment: I did this in `viewDidLoad` but no change. I have the page and only inside the viewtable it is scrollable, not the whole page. What I did: I have an UIView and put all elements there, then I used an UIScrollView put this onto the UIView and put all elements on this scrollview. Then I have in my interface `IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView`, defined the property and synthesize and that was it. From Files owner I connect it to the myScrollView and then from the TableView the dataSource and delegate to the File#s Owner.

Comment: `- (void) viewDidLoad { ... myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);`

Comment: 2 things. The units you use when creating programmatic UIs != pixels. They are 'points'. Secondly, the CGSizeMake value has to be bigger than the height of all your content. You might want to pull the UIScrollView off of the view and keep it referenced in the nib. Then do addSubview. It'll make managing your stuff a lot easier.

Comment: How can I do the addSubview? what is the parameter argument? It works by setting the second argument of CGSizeMake to i.e. 800.

Comment: `[addSubview myUIScrollView];` But that's not going to solve your scrolling issue until you have the CGSizeMake stuff working right. It's just going to keep you sane a little longer :P

Comment: I set it to 800, and now I can scroll the whole screen, but the UITableView inside is only scrollable inside his boundaries. But I want to have it scrollable with the whole page.

Comment: I think if you set the clipsToBounds (??) property of the tableView, it should respond to touches that get dragged out of it.

Comment: So I should do into the `viewDidLoad`: `myTableView.clipToBounds = YES;`? Unfortunately, it does not take effect.